# PHP - Show attachment title, if it's null, show post title

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, attachment

I want to implement a variation of the code below. This code currently shows a post's attachment title.

How I can modify the code so if there is no attachment it shows the post title.?

This is code for pulling first attachment title.

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'post_mime_type' => 'image' ,'post_status' => null, 'numberposts' => 1, 'post_parent'  => $post->ID );
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
$image_title = $attachment->post_title;?>
<?php echo $image_title; ?><?php } } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'post_mime_type' => 'image' ,'post_status' => null, 'numberposts' => 1, 'post_parent'  => $post->ID );
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        $image_title = $attachment->post_title;
        if($image_title) {
            echo $image_title; 
        } else {
            the_title();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exacly what i wanted.

Comment: Do you perhaps know how to make this code work with situations where there are no attachments, as well as blank attachments?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean to be honest. Maybe try adding an else after the if($attachments) to display the_title() ?

Comment: I added another " else { the_title();} " after last } and it does work like i wanted it to. Thanks

Comment: What happened? In the comment you've deleted you said it was working?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be the [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function and a ternary expression

```
$image_title = ( ! empty( $attachment->post_title) )? 
    $attachment->post_title: // use the attachment title if it is not empty
    $post->post_title;       // otherwise use the post title
```

Comment: Just tested this code as well, and it works like i wanted. But why is it the best way? The other code with else works as well, from technical side this way is more optimised? thanks anyway

Comment: It is the most concise way to do the variable assignment and lets you work with that value later on without having to run the if/else later in the code.

Comment: I checked it on different site, and unfortunately this doesn't work as i hoped. It does not show post titles if attachment doesnt exist. (only if it's without title set) How to change it to make it work?

Comment: You are iterating through attachments, so it has to exists if you are inside the loop.